# how to handle configuration change in android from lower versions(2.2) to ICS(3.2) and higher

Tags: android, orientation

I want my application to run with minimum api level 8...I tried with android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"..In lower versions,onConfigurationchanged() method is getting called and orientation is handled..but when i run in 3.2 and higher versions onConfigurationchanged() is not called and activity is re-created.
 So i added android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|ScreenSize" but when i compiled this my application cannot run in versions below 3.2 ICS..what should i do to handle the configuration change in all versions from 2.2 to 4.0.1 without re-creating the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest? For example,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Your code should work as long as your `targetSdkVersion` is greater than or equal to `13`. Make sure you are building your project against SDK version `3.2` or greater as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should add parameter "screenSize" to

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

**[Documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):**

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).